# exporting same named variable and function in nodejs

Tags: node.js, module

Could you please explain me, in case of having same names for variable and function, how to export and access it in another module in NodeJS?﻿

Thank you in Advance

Comment: do you mean having same names for variable and function in different classes, am I right?

Comment: Thank you for your res.If it is different classes. then we can import those classes in different local variables to access the members of the class like,                         var one = require('./file1.js') .                                                                 
var two = require('./file2.js')                                   
console.log(one.name);                                         
console.log(two.name);                                                                         
Am expecting the some possibilities  of having same variables and method names in a module